Using Winforms .NET framework JsonSerializer to serialize a string of filepath but it's returning a filepath including /debug/ folder path
I am an old noobie so I am sorry if I'm confusing.
I am creating a music player app in .NET Framework Winforms.
All I have been trying to do is create a method that serializes the string of folder path to our music folder, deserialize the folder path, read the then deserialized folder path which will be showing inside a text box.
JsonString jsonstring = new JsonString
{
    defaultMediaLocation = @"C:Media\"
};

public string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "MediaLocation.json";


public void SerializeJson(JsonString jsonstring, string path)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
    using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
    {   
        serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, jsonstring.defaultMediaLocation);
        jsonWriter.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
}

public string ReadJson()
{
   

    char[] charsToTrim = { '"'};

    var jsonread = File.ReadAllText(path).Trim(charsToTrim);
    
    return jsonread;
}


So In the end, it CORRECTLY shows the folder path (C:Media) showing inside the aforementioned textbox, but every time we try to play music, we get a message saying;
"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\it\Source\Repos\2PGMusicPlayerWin2\2PGMusicPlayerWin\bin\Debug\Media\MediaLocation.json'"
which is weird, because it should be trying to play music straight from C:\Media which, again, is correctly showing in the textbox and not from debug path.
Please help!

I can’t quite work out what your program is doing, but always use Path.Combine rather than joining strings together to make a path

Also should  C:Media be C:\Media? (I removed the end slash as it seemed to break comment formatting)

Can you update the question with the snippet of code that throws that specific error?

That path you show : "C:\Users\it... bin\Debug\Media\MediaLocation.json" is very likely in the "media" subfolder of the location of your application (whether or not that folder exists). It's what the system would resolve when looking for "Media\MediaLocation.json" (assuming your app doesn't change the current working directory). Using the methods of System.IO.Path methods like Combine and the various GetXxx methods is advisable. In particular, putting temporary calls to Path.GetFullPath can usually speed up your debugging

When combining paths always use Path.Combine. Don't use string concatenation.

Thank you oh kind people for trying to help. In the end, I found out that the way JSON Serializer converts the string of file path for example my  C:\Media\ to "C:\\Media\". I definitely will you the Path.Combine method in the future thanks again!

If you use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, you'll get the application's startup directory being executed, which is the debug directory
